# Scheduler Job in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is there any way out where we can have a scheduler job in snowflake to run some queries at particular interval daily, monthly or weekly? Thank you

Comment: This was the first google entry https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks.html

Answer (score 1):

Tasks can run according to a specified execution configuration, using any combination of a set interval and/or a flexible schedule using a subset of familiar cron utility syntax.
Tasks currently run in user-specified warehouses but will eventually run in a serverless environment using Snowflake-supplied compute resources.

Tasks can be combined with table streams for continuous ELT workflows to process recently changed table rows. Streams ensure exactly-once semantics for new or changed data in a table.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the snowflake task to execute a query at a particular interval daily, monthly, or weekly. The only limitation of this is snowflake supports a single query within a task. If you are interested to execute multiple queries in the same interval, you can combine them into a snowflake stored procedure and call that stored procedure within the task.